# Do internet bandwidth get used when I am using vpn or proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

In my country, most of porn sites are banned, so i choose VPN & proxy to browse, it means my ISP get change if i connect to VPN or proxy, so my Internet bandwidth get used when I connect to vpn or proxy?

Comment: Ye​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌s.

Comment: in some rare cases, a very small ISP will use technology for bandwidth management, that can be bypassed via a VPN (and you can always reduce usage by using VPN compression), but we have no idea whether your ISP is vulnerable, nor could we advise you if it were.

Comment: When you connect to a VPN all bandwidth goes through the VPN tunnel but also your ISP the traffic within the tunnel can be encrypted if it's setup to be encrypted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a VPN may actually increase your Internet usage because of protocol overhead.

A VPN tunnel is really just encapsulating your packets inside other packets, so, at the very least, you add IP header overhead. Encryption can expand the data being transferred, so an encrypted tunnel could make more data just from encryption.

In any case, the VPN packets must still go through your Internet link to your ISP, so they count as Internet traffic toward your usage cap

.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes

Accessing the VPN or proxy is done via *your* Internet connection. The VPN or proxy's function is to act as an intermediary that masks your computer's identity, but your Internet connection is still required to do this, so you still need bandwidth on your end of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

That connection moves its data through your ISP, so yes, your Internet bandwidth gets used.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't know how to make this any simpler, sorry.

Comment: @fixer1234 Too technical, needs to be explained in simple terms. Protocol overhead, encapsulation, ... no, it won't reach his head.

Comment: "Serving suggestion".  Feel free to roll it back or play with it.